# Dynamically load/populate data based on scrollbar handle position?

Tags: pyqt, scrollbar, qtreewidget

My PyQt application pulls data from third party API calls.  The dataset returned usually contains in the neighborhood of hundreds of items.  On occasion, the dataset returned contains in the tens of thousands of items.  On those occasions, the interface is painfully slow to display - too slow to be useful.

To speed things up, I would like to load less of the data during the initial load.  I would like to be able to populate the interface based on the scrollbar handle position.  I would prefer that the scrollbar have the correct range as soon as the widget is displayed, but as the user scrolls, the data that they should be seeing is populated into the widget (a QTreeWidget in this case). This is to say that I'd rather the user didn't have to scroll to the bottom of the widget to load more data at the bottom & therefore change the range of the scroll bar.

I believe QSqlTable behaves this way out of the box, but because I'm not relying on sql queries (and because some of the columns' data is calculated by the GUI), I don't believe I can use that module.  Is this possible with QTreeWidget and w/o direct sql calls?

Answer (score 1):

There is built-in functionality for this in Qt model-view framework. See `QAbstractItemModel.canFetchMore()` and `QAbstractItemModel.fetchMore()` [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore)

Oh, I've just realised you aren't using MVF but stand-alone QTreeWidget instead. If you are dealing with large data and require such a functionality, a switch to MVF may be a right thing to do.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the time budget to switch to MVC.  I know that's the right way to do this, but I've inherited this code & have to work with what I've got.